# Software Inventory for Django Projects and their Apps

Tags: inventory, django

We would like to have a software inventory of our code base which runs in production.

## The data structure

- We have N customers.
- Each customer has N django projects.
- Each django project includes N apps.

## "must" features

- Store inventory data in postgres.
- Collect inventory data (no manual input)

## "nice to have" features

- django based solution
- Store the history, too: to answer this question "Since when does customer X run app Y?".